# Limited rows count in LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: **LOCALES** and **CUISINES** (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee2419/2) and I need to find all the **LOCALES** which have "english" **CUISINE**. Simple!

But **LOCALES** have the premium or not (1 or 0). And now those with no premium can be searched only by 3 (finite number) types of **CUISINE**, while those with premium don't have any limits. In the fiddled case the **LOCALE** named `NO PREMIUM` shouldn't be in the result, because "english" **CUISINE** is the 4th on its list of **CUISINES**, and I need to search only 3.

How to limit **CUISINES** in my query. I mean, how to limit number of rows in LEFT OUTER JOIN? Or maybe you have any better ideas?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.
As for better ideas... well, let's just start with the above.

Comment: You need something to sort `CUISINES` table by... Adding an `ORDER` column would help a lot....

Comment: ok, they're naturally ordered by id and the fiddle is enclosed in the first line of my question